# How to roll the data on "n" months partitions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like below:

```
month    year    value
1        2019    20
2        2019    13  
3        2019    10 
4        2019    20
5        2019    13  
6        2019    10 
7        2019    20
8        2019    13  
9        2019    10 
10        2019    20
11        2019    13  
12        2019    10 
1        2020    20
2        2020    13  
3        2020    10 
4        2020    40
```

Please assume that each month and year occurs multiple times and also there are much more columns. What I wanted to create is multiple dataframes in a 6 months window. I dont want to have aggregations.
The partitioned dataset should include data in the below criteria. Please help me with pandas. I know the naive way is to manually use conditions to select the dataframe. But I guess there will be more effective way in doing this operations at one go.

```
 month 1-6 year 2019
 month 2-7 year 2019
 month 3-8 year 2019
 month 4-9 year 2019
 month 5-10 year 2019
 month 6-11 year 2019
 month 7-12 year 2019
 month 8-1 year 2019,2020
 month 9-2 year 2019,2020
 month 10-3 year 2019,2020
 month 11-3 year 2019,2020
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
for i, j in zip(range(1,12), range(6,13)):
    print(i,j)    # this is for 2019
```

I can take this i and j and plug it in months and repeat the same for 2020 as well. But there will be a better way where it would be easy to create a list of dataframes.

Comment: How far did you try?

Comment: Hi Joshua, Thank you for reaching out. I have updated the question with "what I have tried so far' .

Answer (score 0):

With a datetime index and pd.Grouper, you can proceed as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12,3),  
                  index = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.now(), periods = 12), 
                  ) 
df_grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = "6M"))
[df_grouped.get_group(x) for x in df_grouped.groups]
```

Comment: The month and year occurs multiple times. So we cannot directly give index like this